# vb.net module visibility

Tags: vb.net, module

If I have a `module` in a `VB.Net` class library, will it's visibility be limited to the assembly? What I'm looking for is the VB.Net equivalent of a `C#` `internal static` class. Does anyone know the equivalent?

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ is a get resource when you know the syntax in c# and want the equivalent in vb.net or vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Friend Module` will do what you want.